# Full Online System Backup Debian

Tags: image, backup, system, debian

I'm not familier with linux and debian system I work most with windows computers. But one of my clients uses debian linux web server and I need to upgrade the server's raid array.

Before I do anything with the server I would need a full system backup. I search through the internet for solution and also this site, but I haven't found acceptable answer.

I would need something like LVM snapshot, but I don't want to convert everything to LVM partition just for a backup. I found the DD to make bit by bit copy of the hardrive, but I should unmount the drive for it and I don't too much service offline. The reconfiguration of the raid will be enough offline. I found solution like TAR the necessary files and send through SSH, but it isn't a full system backup. I do backup every month form the files and settings. 
I need a solution that makes an easy restorable image file of the server for emergency case. If the raid configuration fails I will need SOS restoration of the full system to the old config.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

It's not a snapshot, but if you don't want to use LVM, it's a start.

Comment: How should I deal with locked files (example DB files of mysql)?